# Не могу поменять jdk 1.8.0 на jdk 10?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Итак вышла новая версия jdk и грех её не попробовать. Вот только, когда я вношу изменения, Idea ругается мол не то!??

[image]

Как правильно поступить  в этом случае. Ведь вы наверное увидели что перед десяткой у меня не получилось поменять девятку.

Может я дебил может Idea.

Win10 если что. 
Intellij Idea 2017.2.1 ...

В чем суть ошибки и как её исправить

Comment: Прежде всего обнови саму Intellij Idea до последней версии

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наверное версия Idea старая и jdk 10 нужно устанавливать с официального саита, а не из глубин интернета.

Jdk 10 http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk10-downloads-4416644.html

Idea https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/.

Не стоит  использовать софт пиратку лучше купить лицензионный

Comment: Я понял. Тупо jdk 10 криво установился.